# why the condition x!=15 is evaluating as true giving the output 1

Tags: c, operators

```
int x = 15 ;
printf ("\n%d %d %d", x != 15, x = 20, x < 30 );
```

I was studying C and solving a pseudocode. I tried to solve it and my answer was `0 20 1`,
but when I tried to compile and check the answer was `1 20 1`.
Can someone explain me why this is happening?

When I tried to interchange the condition to `printf ("\n%d %d %d", x = 20,x != 15, x < 30 );` and here I got answer to be `20 0 1`

Why is this happening?

Comment: This isn't just an order of evaluation issue. `x = 20` is unsequenced in relation to the unrelated value access of `x` in the other arguments. This code invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The order of evaluation of function argument is unspecified. So, if you have an expression which alters the value of one variable, which appears as other arguments in a conditional check, there's no guarantee for the result.